# Matching a quadratic model to a linear model to give constant false alarm rate

Tags: statistical-significance, modeling, curve-fitting

I have a linear model which estimates the false alarm rate on different regions of an image on thresholding. Meaning the rate of false alarms is constant for all regions when a single threshold is applied.How can I match a quadratic model which gives the same constant false alarm rate as the linear model

Comment: You are close to the problem and so your description makes sense to you, but for those who are - like me - farther away from it could you please elaborate a bit more? For example, I do not know how an image area can have a false alarm rate, or what variables are used in your modeling.

Comment: I have images of many dies and for each 2 dies I have a difference image.The difference images contain noise and potential anomalies in the pattern.Now i have a linear model and use some translation and scaling to bring all the distributions (difference image from all dies)(count vs Grey level) so that all distributions will match in terms of false alarm count per unit area on application of a single threshold.The question is can I match the linear model with a quadratic model.Meaning single threshold will give same alarm count per unit area.Hopefully I am clear.

Comment: basically the difference image looks semi exponential.So i am taking log to get a get a straight line on which I do a linear fit.The thing is sometimes the distribution is parabolic.So I want to basically evaluate the error of the model.(Not the fit).But before that I want to match the linear model with a quadratic model and see how the SNR changes based on a threshold.

Comment: From what I understand of the problem, to me this would best be determined empirically, by experimentation, comparing as many known linear cases to results from quadratic modeling.